# When should one pass data to a template and when call a function?

Tags: go

When having passed functions to a template via [Funcs](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs), these can be called directly in the template. Data can also be passed via [Execute](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute).

So far, I've passed general data to the template and only called functions when for example I had to format a Time or some String. See below.

Combining both:

```
{{range .AssignedTickets}}
  <p>FormatDate .Date</p>
  <p>{{FormatEditorName .EditorID}}</p>
{{end}}
```

Mostly using functions, assuming only `EditorID` was passed as data:

```
{{$assignedTickets := GetAssignedTickets .EditorID}}
{{range $assignedTickets}}
  <p>FormatDate .Date</p>
  <p>{{FormatEditorName .EditorID}}</p>
{{end}}
```

---

When should I pass data and when should I call a function? Are there performance reasons as to avoid one of these (I'd guess I should avoid calling functions inside the template?)

Comment: The big advantage of data passed in is: It is constant. If you call a functions twice (e.g. current date) it _might_ return two different values (e.g. if one call happened right before midnight and the other after midnight). Also: Functions which may fail are best handled outside the template. Calling formatting functions (display logic): yes as these functions are deterministic and do not fail. Calling business logic: No.

Comment: @Volker Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big advantage of data passed in is: It is constant. If you call a functions twice (e.g. current date) it might return two different values (e.g. if one call happened right before midnight and the other after midnight).
Also: Functions which may fail are best handled outside the template.

Calling formatting functions (display logic): yes as these functions are deterministic and do not fail.
Calling business logic: No.

Comment: Thanks, seems intuitive. Do you know if a performance argument could be made? Not needed for me, but would be a good resource.

Comment: @CarstenHagemann Performance: slightly worse as the template engine has to go through reflection to call your function, while if you do that in Go code, that obviously does not need reflection. But doing this once shouldn't matter, as Volker said: measure if it needs to be addressed.

Comment: Templates are made of reflection. The only real way to avoid reflection in templates is not to use them at all.